# How can I revert a jQuery function which disallows copy/paste?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I would like to know what the opposite of this function that prevent copy and cut in the site:

```
$('body').on('cut copy', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
});
```

I want to revert this function in some pages, that is why I would like to know

Comment: `bind` has been deprecated you should use `on` instead. Instead of reverting the function, why not just unbind the events - you can use [`.off`](https://api.jquery.com/off/)

Comment: I would like to wright a function that enable copy and cut. I tried to wright $('body').off('cut copy', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    });
but is not working

Comment: Read the [documentation for .off()](https://api.jquery.com/off/) more carefully, you haven't understood how it works.